# errorBody() returns null in Retrofit2 despite a rawResponse

Tags: android, error-handling, response, retrofit2

Maybe I don't understand apis or Retrofit2, but when I get a `500 Internal Server Error`, I would like to notify the user appropriately.

When I log the incoming response after receiving this error, I get `null` when I log like this:

```
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Log.d(TAG, g.toJson(response.errorBody()));
```

However, when I log my response, I see `code`, `message`, etc inside the `rawResponse`, like this:

(Some of the JSON has been removed for brevity)

```
{  
   "rawResponse":{  
    "body":{  
      "contentLength":0,
         "contentType":{  
            "mediaType":"text/html",
            "subtype":"html",
            "type":"text"
          }
      },
      "code":500,
      "headers":{  
         "namesAndValues":[  ]
      },
      "message":"Internal Server Error",
      "networkResponse":{  
         "code":500,
         "headers":{  },
         "message":"Internal Server Error",
         "protocol":"HTTP_1_1",
         "receivedResponseAtMillis":1509415428600,
         "request":{  },
         "sentRequestAtMillis":1509415428428
      },
      "protocol":"HTTP_1_1",
      "receivedResponseAtMillis":1509415428600,
      "request":{  },
      "sentRequestAtMillis":1509415428428
   }
}
```

So what I am not understanding is, where does `response.errorBody` draw from then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unsuccessful response the errorBody is nothing but the body itself.

This can be verified by looking at Retrofit source code - [Response.java](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Response.java)

```
  /** Create an error response from {@code rawResponse} with {@code body} as the error body. */
  public static <T> Response<T> error(ResponseBody body, okhttp3.Response rawResponse) {
    checkNotNull(body, "body == null");
    checkNotNull(rawResponse, "rawResponse == null");
    if (rawResponse.isSuccessful()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawResponse should not be successful response");
    }
    return new Response<>(rawResponse, null, body);
  }

  private final okhttp3.Response rawResponse;
  private final @Nullable T body;
  private final @Nullable ResponseBody errorBody;

  private Response(okhttp3.Response rawResponse, @Nullable T body,
      @Nullable ResponseBody errorBody) {
    this.rawResponse = rawResponse;
    this.body = body;
    this.errorBody = errorBody;
  }
```

So in above case code is 500 which is unsuccessful and body is empty.
This same empty body is initialized to errorBody and hence you get null

Comment: Actually, I did see that and completely dismissed it a while ago.  But on my second look, I see exactly what you are saying.  And since my `body` is returning back with a content length of 0.  That explains the null.  I guess the problem is my api not returning back error codes on it's own.

Comment: Marked correct, but follow up question.  Can a 500 code ever return a body back?  I understand why other codes such as 4XX can.

Comment: Yes even 5xx Server errors should send the body back to client. You can read more about response code on Wikipedia page [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors)